# AngularJS ng-show not working,I have checked syntax and it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need some help my `ng-show` is not working

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">NotesTest:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <textarea class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-invalid ng-invalid-maxlength" id="note" name="note" ng-maxlength="255" ng-model="formData.adjustment.note"></textarea>
        </div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="label label-danger ng-hide" ng-show="formData.adjustment.note.$error.maxlength">255 only</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? Show your controller code and console errors you are getting.

The expression you have should evaluate to truthy or falsey. So formData.adjustment.note.$error.maxlength should be a boolean value.

Comment: I dont have controller code, I have to have controller code ?

Comment: Well by default I believe ngModel watches the model by reference not value. So it wouldn't fire the ng-show based on the value of textarea unless you were were . Are you expecting this to show up on the form submit? You'll need to reference to form's name

If that's your only input you can use ng-dirty like so:

    <span class="label label-danger ng-hide" ng-show="formName.note.$dirty">255 only</span>

Comment: yes I want to show the span when my text area exceed the 255 characters, I thought I did not need any controller functions. do you know how I can validate that if my textarea exceed the 255 characters then show the span label? I look at some examples in the Angular website, but I am not sure where to place the code in the proactor.js in the example of this link  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input, I have a controller but the functions this is what I am doing in the controller.  $scope.formData.adjustment = {
          note: "";}

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figure out that what is cousing the issue is this "ng-valid-maxlength" inside my form class attribute, do you know why this is causing the ng-show to not work ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should wrap your form in form tags with a name attribute. You can then reference the form via that name.

```
<span class="label label-danger ng-hide" ng-show="form.note.$error.maxlength">255 only</span>
```

granted your form element name is `form`  and your input has a name of `note`

Please see this example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength

and this fiddle of your code

https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/17/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figure out that what is cousing the issue is this "ng-valid-maxlength" inside my form class attribute, do you know why this is causing the ng-show to not work ?